# Getting gmail attachment size programmatically before downloading

Tags: android, email-attachments

I am downloading my Gmail attachment using Multipart/Bodypart concept.
The downloading is fine and working. But not able to get the attachment size before actually downloading the file.

Here is code snippet:

```
Store store = s.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "mygmailaddress@gmail.com", "password");
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Misc");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages();
Multipart m=(Multipart)msgs[inbox.getMessageCount()-1].getContent(); //taking latest email
for(int i = 0;i < m.getCount(); i++){
BodyPart bp = m.getBodyPart(i);
String disposition = bp.getDisposition();
if(disposition!=null &&(disposition.equals("ATTACHMENT"))){
/*downloading code here */
}
}
```

How to get attachment size before actually downloading it?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                m.writeTo(os);
                int bytes = os.size();
```

Comment: actually I have already have inputstream stored using bp.getInputStream() in a var. How can I use that var to get the size?

Comment: that variable is your total bytes. so count that as your size. you can  manipulate that bytes as per your requirement.

Comment: U can not get the size from inputstrram